# What is more idiomatic in go?

Tags: go, interface

I'm designing an interface and wonder, what's the more idiomatic way:

```
func GetUser(id string) (*User, error)
```

or

```
func GetUser(id string, u *User) error
```

Comment: Obviously the later. Where on earth did you see the second variant in the standard library?

Comment: If that’s supposed to be an output parameter, Go has multiple return parameters, there no reason for output parameters on their own. I that’s not, you need to provide more info.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be an output parameter.

Comment: I thought about `func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error`

Comment: Both are idiomatic (the name not withstanding). But they do entirely different things.

Comment: @Volker I think you mean "obviously the former", based on the second sentence.

Comment: Both forms appear in the stdlib. sql.DB.Query and runtime.MemStats, for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on the intended purpose.

If the purpose is to ­— given an identifier — fetch the information
about the user *and fill a user-supplied variable* (of an appropriate type)
with that information, then it's the case for
`func GetUser(id string, u *User) error`.

If the purpose is to fetch that information and *create a new value*
(of an appropriate type) containing that information and return it
(or — as in your case — a pointer to it) to the user, then it's the case
for `func GetUser(id string) (*User, error)`.

So, in the end, it's not about comparing "idiomaticity factor" of the
two solutions; they capture different ways to deal with the obtained
data.